# SharePoint 2010 Auto-populate "Reassign Task" field in Approval Process Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2010, picker, infopath2010

In SharePoint Designer 2010 and InfoPath 2010,  I am trying to automatically populate the field "Reassign Task To" field when a user clicks the "Reassign Task" button (this is within the Approval Process Workflow).  I have tried to do this by editing the workflow from within SharePoint Designer 2010 and I have tried to do it from InfoPath 2010, but from both places I can't seem to do it.  I can auto populate other person/group pickers but not that one.  Does anyone know how to do this?